# Return a string from a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In an SQL statement how does one return a string value dependent on the value in another column?

Language is T-SQL

i want a sub query to return the result of the following pseudo code expression into  a new column called Current_YTD

```
IF(Committed_Date >= '01/04/2011') THEN Current_YTD = 'Y'
```

Committed_Date is a `DateTime` type

Comment: Doh! should have mentioned that. it's Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server (appears likely from your question history), you need the CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Committed_Date >= '01/04/2011' THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
    END AS Current_YTD
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN Committed_Date >= '01/04/2011' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END
FROM <table>
```

Comment: I was the first answer and it's the same answer that got the correct answer :D  You rock Ada!